# Error when trying to install drivers for TP-LINK AC600 T2U

Tags: drivers, make, tp-link

Hi thanks to anybody who try to answer my question, I only just started using Ubuntu about a month ago so it might just be a rookie mistake
I am running Ubuntu 17.04

When trying to install drives for this device I got the error

```
Makefile:405: recipe for target 'LINUX' failed
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

And the commands I had done before this was

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential
mkdir ~/src
cd ~/src
git clone https://github.com/zma/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916
cd mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916
make clean
make
```

And the error was received after the make command

Because I could not fit all the code from the make command this link is for a Google document with the code.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MwSLatz2-M1PSjy9bRcnUnzAOwFKXHxW4-ZJOdtd8d0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors listed simply indicate that the circa-2013 driver is too old to compile on your modern 4.10.0-xx kernel. In fact, having tried many different versions of mt7610u from github and other sources, I am unaware of *any* driver that compiles successfully and then works; that is, connects and pulls web pages, emails, etc.

I regret that I can offer no better solution.